# What does Decorated Suspension, a type of nonchord tone, mean in this below explanation?

Tags: theory, piano, nonchord-tones

### I'm learning about decorated suspension. But I don't understand the explanation below. Could you guys help me with this?

P/s: I type the script of explanation below, so you guys with smartphone screen can read it more easier.

- **DECORATING THE SUSPENSION**

The non-suspending voice is usually stable (i.e.
does not move) during stages 2 and 3 of the suspension.

However, one way of DECORATING a suspension to change the note of the
non-suspending voice at stage 3. This voice would jump to another chord note,
usually another **imperfect consonance**, at the point of resolution. This tends to
happen more with 7-6 and 2-3 suspensions than with 4-3. It can also occur in a 9-
8 suspension. The following shows some previous examples which have been
decorated in this way; play them and comment on them (are they related?):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author wants to illustrate a suspension with and without decoration.

This part: `S: 7-(6) 3!` in plain English means: `suspension: seventh above will normally resolve to a sixth where the top voice moves down by step and the lower voice doesn't move, but instead it can be "decorated" where the top voice moves down by step *and* the lower voice moves to a chord tone forming a third between the two voices."

The un-decorated suspension would look like...

[image]

In the decorated suspension, the lower voice is decorated by moving from `D` to `G` (circled in red.)

[image]

- The bar between `7` and `6` means the lower voice is held and therefore the changing intervals of a seventh to a sixth are formed by the movement of the higher voice.
- The parenthesis around six `(6)` mean it is the expected interval of the un-decorated resolution
- The exclamation point after three `3!` means "surprise, this isn't the standard resolution, it's a *decorated* resolution."